# Как продолжить родительский цикл с помощью continue? Си

Tags: c

Есть обычный цикл for:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < l2; ++i) //родительский цикл
    {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < l1; ++i2) //вложенный цикл
        {
             if (условие)
             {
                 продолжить родительский цикл
             }
             что-нибудь другое;
        }
        сдесь тоже какой-то код
    }
```

Как можно это реализовать? Гуглил но ничего не нашел. Надо реализовать именно так

Правка, мой косяк:

После цикла тоже есть код который будет выполняться

Comment: в таком варианте — просто `break` из вложенного... а можно вообще условие в заголовок включить...

Comment: либо как вариант `if (!условие) { что-нибудь другое; }`

Comment: @Bogdan я не дописал еще действия после цикла. Уже отредактировал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < l2; ++i) //родительский цикл
{
    int continueParent = 0;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < l1; ++i2) //вложенный цикл
    {
         if (условие)
         {
             continueParent = 1; // продолжить родительский цикл
             break;
         }
         /* что-нибудь другое; */
    }
    if (continueParent)
        continue;
    /* здесь тоже какой-то код */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я в коде не все написал, уже отредактировал

Answer (score 3):

Нужно использовать дополнительный флаг:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l2; ++i) {//родительский цикл
    bool skip_iteration = 0;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < l1; ++i2) { //вложенный цикл
         if (/*условие*/) {
             skip_iteration = 1;
             break;
         }
         // что-нибудь другое;
    }
    if (skip_iteration) { continue; }
    // сдесь тоже какой-то код
}
```

Также это один из немногих вариантов, когда допустимо вместо лишнего флага использовать `goto`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l2; ++i) {//родительский цикл
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < l1; ++i2) { //вложенный цикл
         if (/*условие*/) {
             goto skip_iteration;
         }
         //что-нибудь другое;
    }
    // сдесь тоже какой-то код
    skip_iteration:
}
```